# Is there any standard visual studio 2008 plugin avialable for to trace/log constructor and destructor calls of C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on a c++ project. I am trying to find out memory Leaks from RC Purify but not getting satisfying output. I am planning to either write logs in all constructor and destructor to validate mem-leak or trying to find out some plugin which will do so.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a plugin, but you can instrument your classes by adding a base object counter:

```
template <typename T>
struct Counter {
   static atomic_int alive;
   Counter() {
      ++alive;
   }
   ~Counter() {
      --alive;
   }
};
template <typename T>
atomic_int Counter::alive = 0;
```

And then for each instrumented class:

```
class Instrumented : Counter<Instrumented>   // CRTP
{ ... };
```

In the code you can use:

```
std::cout << Counter<Instrumented>::alive << std::endl;
```

To see how many objects of type `Instrumented` have been created and not destroyed.

Note that this is a poor man's choice, and it will yield worse results than tools like Purify or valgrind (i.e. it only tracks objects that are instrumented and will not detect memory lost due to badly written destructors or incorrect resetting of internal pointers, it is intrusive and you have to explicitly add code to obtain the results --or use a debugger...) But it I have used it in the past to help understand some issue.

Comment: It's also one off _during_ the execution of ctors and dtors, and currently not really thread-safe.

Comment: I fixed the thread safety, in the context I used it in the past there were no threading issues. As of the *one off* error, it is only meant to be used as a tool to detect when objects are leaked, it does not mean to be precise. The one-off (or even multiple off in the event of multiple threads all creating/destroying objects of the type) should be understood as a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinDbg to try to find memory leaks download it from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009, turn on gflags user stack trace for your leaking app at command prompt or Debugging tools command prompt:

`gflags /i MyApp.exe +ust`

you can then either attach or launch your application from WinDbg, at the command prompt for WinDbg enter:

`.symfix;.reload;g`

Then when your app has run enough for the leak to occur go back to WinDbg press `ctrl+break` and then enter `!heap -l` and it will try to find leaks for you. There is a good walkthrough here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg and http://cprogrammers.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/windows-memory-leak-analysis-using.html.

It could also be a handle leak, in which case when WinDbg attaches enter:

`!htrace -enable` this enables handle tracing and takes a snapshot, then do some stuff in your app, break in WinDbg `ctrl+Break` and enter `!htrace -snapshot` and then `!htrace -diff` and it will list all the handles that have not been released since the last snapshot. Good luck.